# What is proper naming convention for MSVC dlls, static libraries and import libraries

Tags: dll, naming-conventions, visual-c++, cmake, static-libraries

What is standard or "most-popular" naming convention for MSVC library builds.

For example, for following platforms library `foo` has these conventions:

Linux/gcc:

```
shared: libfoo.so
import: ---
static: libfoo.a
```

Cygwin/gcc:

```
shared: cygfoo.dll
import: libfoo.dll.a
static: libfoo.a
```

Windows/MinGW:

```
shared: libfoo.dll
import: libfoo.dll.a
static: libfoo.a
```

What should be used for MSVC buidls? As far as I know, usually names are `foo.dll` and `foo.lib`, but how do you usually distinguish between import library and static one?

**Note:** I ask because `CMake` creates quite [unpleasant](http://art-blog.no-ip.info/cppcms/blog/post/54) collision between them naming both import and static library as `foo.lib`. See [bug report](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=10190). The answer would
help me to convince the developers to fix this bug.

Comment: SCons also "creates (this) quite unpleasant collision" when using _env.SharedLibrary_ and _env.StaticLibrary_ with the same target name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You distinguish between a library and a .dll by the extension.  But you distinguish between a import library and a static library by the *filename*, not the extension.

There will be no case where an import library exists for a set of code that was built to be a static library, or where a static library exists for a dll.  These are two different things.

There is no single MSVC standard filename convention.  As a rule, a library name that ends in "D" is often a debug build of library code, `msvcrtd.dll` vs `msvcrt.dll` but other than that, there are no standards.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by others, there are no standards, but there are popular conventions.  I'm unsure how to unambiguously judge what is the most popular convention.  In addition the nomenclature for static vs. import libraries, which you asked about, there is also an analogous distinction between the naming of Release libraries vs. Debug libraries, especially on Windows.

Both cases (i.e. static vs. import, and debug vs. release) can be handled in one of two ways: different names, or different directory locations.  I usually choose to use different names, because I feel it minimizes the chance of mistaking the library type later, especially after installation or other file moving activities.

I usually use `foo.dll` and `foo.lib` for the shared library on Windows, and `foo_static.lib` for the static library, when I wish to have both shared and static versions.  I have seen others use this convention, so it might be the "most popular".

So I would recommend the following addition to your table:

Windows/MSVC:

```
shared: foo.dll
import: foo.lib
static: foo_static.lib
```

Then in cmake, you could either

```
add_library(foo_static STATIC foo.cpp)
```

or

```
add_library(FooStatic STATIC foo.cpp)
set_target_properties(FooStatic PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "foo_static")
```

if for some reason you don't wish to use "foo_static" as the symbolic library name.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no real 'standard', at least no standard most software would conform to.

My convention is to name my dynamic and static `.lib` equally, but place them in different directories if a project happens to support both static and dynamic linkage. For example:

```
foo-static
   foo.lib

foo
   foo.lib
   foo.dll
```

The library to link against depends on the choice of the library directories, so it's almost totally decoupled from the rest of the build process (it won't appear in-source if you use MSVC's `#pragma comment(lib,"foo.lib")` facility, and it doesn't appear in the list of import libraries for the linker).

I've seen this quite a few times. Also, I think that MSVC/Windows based projects tend to stick more often with a single, official linkage type - either static, *or* dynamic. But that's just my personal observation.

In short:
  *Windows/MSVC*

```
shared: foo.dll
import: foo.lib
static: foo.lib
```

You should be able to use this directory-based pattern with CMAKE (never used it). Also, I don't think it's a 'bug'. It's merely lack of standardization. CMAKE does (imho) the right thing *not* to establish a pseudo-standard if everyone likes it differently.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard naming convention for libraries.  Traditional library names are prefixed with `lib`.  Many linkers have options to prepend `lib` to a library name on the command line.

The static and dynamic libraries are usually identified by their file extension; although this is not required.  So `libmath.a` would be a static library whereas `libmath.so` or `libmath.dll` would be a dynamic library.

A common naming convention is to append the category of the library to the name.  For example, a debug static math library would be 'libmathd.a' or in Windows, 'lib_math_debug'.  Some shops also add Unicode as a filename attribute.

If you want, you can append `_msvc` to the library name to indicate the library requires or was created by MSVC (to differentiate from GCC and other tools).  A popular convention when working with multiple platforms, is to place the objects and libraries in platform specific folders.  For example a `./linux/` folder would contain objects and libraries for Linux and similarly `./msw/` for Microsoft Windows platform.

This is a style issue.  Style issues are often treated like religious issues:  none of them are wrong, there is no universal style, and they are an individual preference.  What ever system you choose, just be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said, there is no single *standard* to file naming on windows.

For our complete product base which covers 100's of exes, dlls, and static libs we have used the following successfully for many years now and it has saved a lot of confusion.  Its basically a mixing of several methods I've seen used throughout the years.

In a nutshell all our files of both a prefix and suffix (not including the extension itself).  They all start with "om" (based on our company name), and then have a 1 or 2 character combination that roughly identifies the area of code.

The suffix explains what type of built-file they are and includes up to three letters used in combination depending on the build which includes Unicode, Static, Debug (Dll builds are the default and have no explicit suffix identifier).  When we started this system Unicode was not so prevalent and we had to support both Unicode and Non-unicode builds (pre Windows 2000 os), now everything is exclusively built unicode but we still use the same nomenclature.

So a typical .lib "set" of files might look like

```
omfThreadud.lib (Unicode/Debug/Dll)
omfThreadusd.lib (Unicode/Static/Debug)
omfThreadu.lib (Unicode/Release/Dll)
omfThreadus.lib (Unicode/static)
```

All files are built-in into a common bin folder, which eliminates a lot of dll-hell issues for developers and also makes it simpler to adjust compiler/linker settings - they all point to the same location using relative paths and there is never any need for manual (or automatic) copying of the libraries a project needs.  Having these suffixes also eliminates any confusion as to what type of file you may have, and guarantees you can't have a mixed scenario where you put down the debug dll on a release kit or vice-versa.  All exes also use a similar suffix (Unicode/Debug) and build into the same bin folder.

There is likewise one single "include" folder, each library has one header file in the include folder that matches the name of the library/dll (for example omfthread.h)  That file itself #includes all the other items that are exposed by that library.  This keeps its simpler if you want functionality that is in foo.dll you just #include "foo.h"; our libraries are highly segmented by areas of functionality - effectively we don't have any "swiss-army knife" dlls so including the libraries entire functionality makes sense.  (Each of these headers also include other prerequisite headers whether they be our internal libraries or other vendor SDKs)

Each of these include files internally uses macros that use #pramga's to add the appropriate library name to the linker line so individual projects don't need to be concerned with that. Most of of our libraries can be built statically or as a DLL and #define OM_LINK_STATIC (if defined) is used to determine which the individual project wants (we usually use the DLLs but in some cases static libraries built-in into the .exe make more sense for deployment or other reasons)

```
#if defined(OM_LINK_STATIC)
 #pragma comment (lib, OMLIBNAMESTATIC("OMFTHREAD"))
#else
 #pragma comment (lib, OMLIBNAME("OMFTHREAD"))
#endif
```

These macros (OMLIBNAMESTATIC & OMLIBNAME) use _DEBUG determine what type of build it is and generate the proper library name to add to the linker line.

We use a common define in the static & dll versions of a library to control proper exporting of the class/functions in dll builds. Each class or function exported from the library is decorated with this macro (the name of which matches the base name for the library, though that is largely unimportant)

```
class OMUTHREAD_DECLARE CThread : public CThreadBase
```

In the DLL version of the project settings we define OMFTHREAD_DECLARE=__declspec(dllexport), in the static library version of the library we define OMFTHREAD_DECLARE as *empty*.

In the libraries header file we define it based on how the client is trying to link to it

```
#if defined(OM_LINK_STATIC)
 #define OMFTHREAD_DECLARE
#else
 #define OMFTHREAD_DECLARE __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

A  typical project that wants to use one of our internal libraries would just add the appropriate include to their stdafx.h (typically) and it just works, if they need to link against the static version they just add OM_LINK_STATIC to their compiler settings (or define it in the stdafx.h) and it again it just works.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there still aren't any conventions with regards to this. Here's an example of how I do it:

{Project}*{SubModule}*{Platform}*{Architecture}*{CompilerRuntime}_{BuildType}.lib/dll

The full filename shall be lowercase only and shall only contain alphanumerics with predesignated underscores. The submodule field, including its leading underscore, is optional.

Project: holds project name/identifier. Preferably as short as possible. ie "dna"

SubModule: optional. holds module name. Preferably as short as possible. ie "dna_audio"

Platform: identifies the platform the binary is compiled for. ie "win32" (Windows), "winrt", "xbox", "android".

Architecture: describes the architecture the binary is compiled for. ie "x86", "x64", "arm". There where architecture names are equal for various bitnesses use its name followed by the bitness. ie. "name16", "name32", "name64"

CompilerRuntime: optional. Not all binaries link to a compiler runtime, but if they do, it's included here. ie "vc90" (Visual Studio 2008), "gcc". Where applicable apartment can be included ie "vc90mt"

BuildType: optional. This can hold letters (in any order desired), each which tell something about the build-specifics. d=debug (omitted if release) t=static (omitted if dynamic) a=ansi (omitted if unicode)

Examples (assuming a project named "DNA"):
dna_win32_x86_vc90.lib/dll
dna_win32_x64_vc90_d.lib/dll
dna_win32_x86_vc90_sd.lib
dna_audio_win32_x64_vc90.lib/dll
dna_audio_winrt_x64_vc110.lib/dll

Comment: CompilerRuntime is like vc141
but in the project file there is only PlatfromToolset defined aka v141
What is the difference?

Comment: @Fantastory Your question is a top-level question (or however Stack Overflow calls it) in and off of itself. The PlatformToolset is more broad than the CompilerRuntime, witth the CompilerRuntime being part of the PlatformToolset. The PlatformToolset also includes things like linker and system libraries. With new versions of Windows new functionality is added. E.g. toasts, or a new version of Direct3D. With that come new libraries, or updated libraries, that export these functions. These are part of the PlatformToolset. Same goes for increased language support, like from C11 to C20.

Comment: Sorry that was because some of the libraries names them as -v140- instead of -vc140-. Concluding vc140 is the correct one.