# Importance of compiling single-threaded v. multi-threaded (and lib naming conventions)?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, naming-conventions, name-decoration

**[ EDIT ] ==>**
To clarify, in those environments where multiple targets are deployed to the same directory, Planet Earth has decided on a convention to append "`d`" or "`_d`" or "`_debug`" to the "`DEBUG`" version (of a library or executable).  Such a convention can be considered "ubiquitous" and "understood", although (of course) not everybody does this.

SIMILARLY, to resolve ambiguity between "shared" and "static" versions of a library, a common convention is to append something to distinguish between the static-and-shared (like "`myfile.lib`" for shared-import-lib-on-Windows and "`myfile_s.lib`" for static-import-lib-on-Windows).  While Posix does not have this ambiguity based on file extension, remember that the file extension is not used on the "link line", so it is similarly useful to be able to explicitly specify the "static" or "shared" version of a library.

For the purpose of this question, both "`debug/release`" and "`static/shared`" are promoted to *"ubiquitous convention to decorate the file name root"*.

***QUESTION:*  Does any other deployment configuration get "promoted" to this level of "ubiquitous convention" such that it would become explicit in the file target root name?**

My current guess is "no".  For the answer to be "Yes", it would require:  More than one configuration for given target is intended to be "used" (and thus deployed to a common directory, which is the assumed basis for the question).

In the past, we compiled with-and-without "web plug-in" capability, which similarly required that name decoration, but we no longer build those targets (so I won't assert that as an example).  Similarly, we sometimes compile with-and-without multi-byte character support, but I hate that, so I won't assert that either.

**[ORIGINAL QUESTION]**

We're **establishing library naming conventions**/policy, **to be applied across languages and platforms** (e.g., we support hybrid products using several languages on different platforms, including C/C++, C#, Java).  A particular goal is to ensure we handle targets/resources for mobile development (which is new to us) in addition to our traditional desktop (and embedded) applications.

Of course, *one* option is to have different paths for targets from different build configurations.  For the purpose of this question, the decision is made to have all targets co-locate to a single directory, and to "decorate" the library/resource/executable name to avoid collisions based on build configuration (e.g., "DEBUG" v. "RELEASE", "static lib" v. "shared/DLL", etc.)

Current decision is similar to others on the web, where we append tokens to avoid naming collisions:

```
  MyName.lib           (release build, import for shared/dll)
  MyName_s.lib         (release build, static lib)

  MyName_d.lib         (debug build, import for shared/DLL)
  MyName_ud.lib        (Unicode/wide-char, debug, import for shared/DLL)
  MyName_usd.lib       (Unicode/wide-char, static lib, debug)
```

(The above are Windows examples, but these policies similarly apply to our POSIX systems.)

These are based on:

```
  d     (release or debug)
  u     (ASCII or Unicode/wide-char)
  s     (shared/DLL or static-lib)
```

*QUESTION:*  We do not have legacy applications that must be compiled single-threaded, and my understanding is that (unlike Microsoft) POSIX systems can link single- and multi-threaded targets into a single application without issue.  Given today's push towards multi-core and multi-threaded, **Is there a need in a *large enterprise* to establish the following to identify "single-" versus "multi-threaded" compiled targets?**

```
  t       (single-threaded or multi-threaded)  *(??needed??)*
```

**...and did we miss any other target collision, like compile with-and-without STL (on C++)?**

As an aside, Microsoft has library naming conventions at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270400(v=vs.60).aspx and their DLL naming conventions at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270964(v=vs.60).aspx

A similar question on SO a year ago that didn't talk about threading and didn't reference the Microsoft conventions can be found at: [What is proper naming convention for MSVC dlls, static libraries and import libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140129/what-is-proper-naming-convention-for-msvc-dlls-static-libraries-and-import-libra)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an ancient compiler.  There is no need to establish such a standard in an enterprise, the vendor has already done this.  Microsoft hasn't shipped a single-threaded version of the CRT for the past 13 years.  Similarly, Windows has been a Unicode operating system for the past 17 years.  It makes zero sense to still write Unicode agnostic code these days.

But yes, the common convention is to append a "d" for the debug build of a library.  And to give a DLL version of a library a completely different name.

Comment: The "unicode/wide-char" is really to handle the "compile-with-wide-char" support, taking the "char" from an (ASCII) octet to a 16-bit short.  We're currently using that switch (sometimes) on MSVS2008.  But, fair point on the single/multi-thread being a legacy consideration:  Hence the question.  (We don't want blow-back when we roll the policy to other sites that doesn't handle single-/multi-threaded distinction, if that is still a reasonable concern.)

Comment: TCHAR was a macro hack for Windows 9x.  The odds that your code ever runs on one are about on par to being able to restore your backup from a floppy.  Setting standards is laudable, don't base them on hopelessly archaic ones.

Comment: We're not using TCHAR today.  The issue is whether "char" is an octet, or 16-bits.  We have third-party libraries and drivers that are sometimes one-or-the-other, and we must compile our code to be consistent.  So, while we agree TCHAR is archaic, the binary size of "char" is a very real problem in today's world.

Comment: No, there is no option that changes the size of the *char* type.  Choosing between wchar_t and char is a programmer's decision.  The compiler *never* considers them equivalent.

Comment: what is the platform with 16 bit char?

Comment: <sigh>, I mis-spoke:  Two issues exist in our current code base related to Unicode/wide-char: (1) wchar_t is sometimes 8-bit and sometimes 16-bit in our third-party libs/drivers (which is why ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Unicode standard 4.0 says you shouldn't use it to store Unicode chars); (2) We *sometimes* compile with multi-byte character support.  The switch was intended to "flag" exceptional issues for us, because we've not yet figured out how to be homogeneous across all targets.

Comment: Unrelated to my problem @David (I mis-spoke), Java has 16-bit char, the Cray supported 32-bit chars, each platform has latitude to make it other-than-an-octet.

Comment: I don't think you can have single source that compiles in both C++ and Java.

Comment: No, wchar_t is never 8 bits.  At least part of this problem must be induced by using a compiler that is so old that it doesn't have a native wchar_t type.  A decent into macro hell is indeed all too common.  No real cure for that.  Join the 21st century and upgrade your tools.  It will hurt for a few months.  Good luck with it.

Comment: @Hans, I mostly agree, but we use compilers and drivers provided by the embedded controller vendor(s). Further, quoting ISO/IEC 10646:2003: ""The width of wchar_t is compiler-specific and can be as small as 8 bits. Consequently, programs that need to be portable across any C or C++ compiler should not use wchar_t for storing Unicode text. The wchar_t type is intended for storing compiler-defined wide characters, which may be Unicode characters in some compilers."

Comment: @charley: either you're following that advice, or you aren't. If you're following it, then you aren't using `wchar_t` for Unicode text, so why are you worried about its size? If you aren't following it, then why are you quoting it as an objection to what Hans says? *On Windows*, `wchar_t` is 16 bit. So if you're using `wchar_t` on Windows, for instance in the Win-specific parts of your portable app, just get on with it, there's no need for agnosticism. If you're using `wchar_t` in portable code then you're in a state of sin already, a naming convention won't get you out of it.

Comment: @Steve: We don't use wchar_t for Unicode, legacy Unicode uses a mix of Qt, MFC::CString, .NET String, and MBCS (which is why we sometimes compile multi-byte character support). A goal is to "standardize", but we're not there yet. (...continued)

Comment: (...continued) The issues relate to linking libs from device vendors (most cross-compilers for low-level hardware are *very* limited in what they chose to support from the C/C++ standard), and establishing conventions for libs we are able to compile (for example, with- and without-multi-byte-character-support).  We're systematically removing all wchar_t because of its ambiguity, but there's some legacy in there too.  So, the goal is convention we can use cross-site, cross-project, and with legacy limitations (for this, conditional compile of multi-byte-character-support).

Comment: +1 this kind of "let's build 2^n versions of our app/lib for every imaginable configuration" mentality is so outdated, and it leads to **more bloat** rather than less, even for the "minimal" config, because of the complexity of managing all the conditional code.

Comment: @R.., it is very common at many development houses to support *both* share lib and static lib building from the same source for *actual use*.  Similarly, "legacy" means you typically have to deal with "With-or-without" support for other common libs, like with-or-without MFC, or with-or-without (C++) STL, or with-or-without support for browser plugins, from the *same source* where that same source is *actually used* in that manner.  The goal is to identify that *minimal* set for *actually used* build targets. In this example, it is not academic:  we ship products with the above build settings.

Comment: One more note (talked to another developer here), apparently the issue was we were using Qt (commercial) which was built-and-shipped with "wchar_t" as a built-in-(native)-type or not (MSVS2008).  We were compiling one way, Qt was distributing another.  That caused a collision.  (Could have been "wchar" or "wchar_t", he couldn't remember).  Does this issue exist for anyone else (we think we have ours resolved)?